# Add an item in a listview by index number

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

Hey all i am trying to find a way to add something to one of the columns in my listview. The way my code is setup is like this:

```
        While dr.Read()
                If dr.IsDBNull(12) Then
                    objItem = lstMaster.Items.Add("nothing")
                Else
                    objItem = lstMaster.Items.Add(dr(12))
                End If

                With objItem
                    If dr.IsDBNull(11) Then
                        .SubItems.Add("nothing")
                    Else
                        .SubItems.Add(dr(11))
                    End If
```

How can i just tell it to put it in the 3rd column (i have 5 total (0-4)) instad of just going down the roll and it falls in order?

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add as many sub-items as you have columns.  Then just index the sub-item you want to change.  For example:

```
    Dim item = ListView1.Items.Add("Test")
    For cnt As Integer = 1 To ListView1.Columns.Count
        item.SubItems.Add("")
    Next
    item.SubItems(3).Text = "Blah"
```